# Как получить текущий регион из windows?

Tags: windows, java

В настройке языков в `windows` есть текущий регион (местоположение), как его получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.list(System.out);
```

При запуске JVM копирует в себя большинство системных свойств оси, если вам повезет geoId также попадет в этот список. У меня выдает что-то типа:

```
file.encoding=Cp1251
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\
gosh.args=--nointeractive
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.version=50.0
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs=c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home=c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_29-b11
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.6
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.version=20.4-b02
line.separator=
path.separator=;
sun.arch.data.model=32
sun.boot.library.path=c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
sun.desktop=windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1251
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
user.country=RU
user.timezone=Europe/Moscow
```

ну и т.д. список длинный.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна функция `WinAPI` под названием [`GetUserGeoID.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318138(v=vs.85).aspx) Из `Java` ее можно вызвать, например, с помощью [`JNA.`](https://github.com/twall/jna)